# Yii: how to put an active timer/elapsed time

Tags: php, ajax, yii

i have this working function in my controller.

```
public function time_elapsed_string($ptime)
{
    $etime = time() - $ptime;

    if ($etime < 1)
    {
        return '0 seconds';
    }

    $a = array( 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60  =>  'year',
                30 * 24 * 60 * 60       =>  'month',
                24 * 60 * 60            =>  'day',
                60 * 60                 =>  'hour',
                60                      =>  'minute',
                1                       =>  'second'
                );

    foreach ($a as $secs => $str)
    {
        $d = $etime / $secs;
        if ($d >= 1)
        {
            $r = round($d);
            return $r . ' ' . $str . ($r > 1 ? 's' : '') . ' ago';
        }
    }
}
```

and call it in my view:

```
$this->time_elapsed_string(strtotime($model->created_on))
```

the output is fine, but how do it update that certain view with out refreshing the page, with a 5 to 10 second interval?

Comment: make an ajax call or implement this timer in JS

Comment: i was hoping yii has a cool and easy way in doing it so.

Comment: save the timestamp in database and compare to that!

Comment: yes it is saved and has a field name created_on, what i would like is, in view, the value updates/change every second or 5 seconds. like this comment here, after the username, '1 min ago' it changes even if i dont refresh the whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you can could implement a timer like functionality with an ajax call with jQuery that updates the value every 5 seconds.

Put your `time_elapsed_string()` method in an action in your controller, and instead of **returning** the output of that action, **echo** it with `JSON::encode`

```
public function actionAjaxElapsedTime()
{
    $ptime = $_POST['ptime'];
    $etime = time() - $ptime;
    if ($etime < 1)
    {
        $data = '0 seconds';
        echo CJSON::encode($data);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
    ....
    foreach ($a as $secs => $str)
    {
        $d = $etime / $secs;
        if ($d >= 1)
        {
            $r = round($d);
            $data = $r . ' ' . $str . ($r > 1 ? 's' : '') . ' ago';
            echo CJSON::encode($data);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your view, you can use an ajax call with the js method `setTimeout()` in the `completed` parameter, like so:

```
(function update() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('yourController/ajaxElapsedTime'); ?>", 
        data: {ptime : <?php echo strtotime($model->created_on); ?>},
        success: function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);
        },
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(update, 5000);
        }
    });
})();
```

In this case the ajax call sends the data in a `POST` to your action, and appends the result into an html element with the class `result`. When the process is completed, `setTimeout` is called to start the whole process again after 5000 milliseconds.

This code isn't tested, but it should give you an idea of how to get there.

Comment: will try out this one, but i basically get the picture now, thanks dude.